# Button moves when resizing page

Tags: html, css, css-position

My submit button moves when I resize the page. This behavior is bad (obviously). What is the correct way to make it so that my button is left aligned to my textarea?

```css
#chatboxTranscript {
  width: 31.25em;
  /* padding: 0em; */
  background-color: #36393f;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  border: 0.125em solid #000;
  /* Increase border width */
  border-radius: 0.3125em 0.3125em 0 0;
  /* Round the border */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 12.5em;
  /* Maintain the height */
}

#chatboxInput {
  top: -0.125em;
  height: 3.35em;
  left: -2.2em;
  width: 37.3em;
  /* Keep the width the same */
  background-color: #36393f;
  /* Keep the color the same */
  border: 0.15em solid #000;
  border-radius: 0 0 0.3125em 0.3125em;
  /* Round the border */
  padding-bottom: 1.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  /* border-top: none; */
  position: relative;
}

.input-group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

button[type="submit"] {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4em;
  top: -0.1em;
  height: 3em;
  margin: 0 -2em;
  border: 0.125em solid #000;
  background-color: #36393f;
  border-radius: 0.3125em;
}
```

```html
<div id="chatbox" class="chatbox" data-role="chatbox">
  <div id="chatboxTranscript" class="chatbox-transcript"></div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <!-- <form action="#" onsubmit="handleChatboxFormSubmit(event);"> -->
    <textarea type="text" name="chatboxInput" id="chatboxInput" /> </textarea>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <!-- </form> -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried multiple ways of fixing using absolute positioning (still same behavior), display (did nothing), margin (moves my textarea to the left) and asking chatgpt (output nonsensical CSS that didn't work).

Comment: Start by fixing your invalid HTML `<textarea type="text" name="chatboxInput" id="chatboxInput" /> </textarea>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

I've removed all position layout styles since they don't help much in your particular layout.

The main issue was the `.input-group` since it didn't have a width and you're using flex for the layout. The content would take the entire width from its parent (`#chatbox`) therefore the button went to the right-hand side of the screen.

To fix this, I simply added a width for the `.input-group` as well as a margin of auto so it now aligns nicely with `#chatboxTranscript` div.

```
#chatboxTranscript {
  width: 31.25em;
  background-color: #36393f;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  border: 0.125em solid #000; /* Increase border width */
  border-radius: 0.3125em 0.3125em 0 0; /* Round the border */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 12.5em; /* Maintain the height */
}

#chatboxInput {
  height: 3.35em;
  width: 37.3em; /* Keep the width the same */
  background-color: #36393f; /* Keep the color the same */
  border: 0.15em solid #000;
  border-radius: 0 0 0.3125em 0.3125em; /* Round the border */
  padding-bottom: 1.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.input-group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 31.25em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

button[type='submit'] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4em;
  height: 3em;
  border: 0.125em solid #000;
  background-color: #36393f;
  border-radius: 0.3125em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#chatboxTranscript {
  width: 31.25em;
  /* padding: 0em; */
  background-color: #36393f;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  border: 0.125em solid #000; /* Increase border width */
  border-radius: 0.3125em 0.3125em 0 0; /* Round the border */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 12.5em; /* Maintain the height */
}
#chatboxInput {
  top: -0.125em;
  height: 3.35em;
  left: -2.2em;
  width: 37.3em; /* Keep the width the same */
  background-color: #36393f; /* Keep the color the same */
  border: 0.15em solid #000;
  border-radius: 0 0 0.3125em 0.3125em; /* Round the border */
  padding-bottom: 1.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  /* border-top: none; */
  position: relative;
}
.input-group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
button[type="submit"] {
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4em;
  top: -0.1em;
  height: 3em;
  margin: 0 -2em;
  border: 0.125em solid #000;
  background-color: #36393f;
  border-radius: 0.3125em;
}

I edited position of button from "reletive" to "fixed". It will work in page.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But this actually broke it more, now the submit button is on the top left of the screen. 
Here is the full code containing HTML and 2 CSS files if you want to see.https://pastebin.com/5i5p3irS